I am trying to wire in a gfci outlet switch combo. I can get the switch to turn on the light but the outlet never gets power
Power goes in to line switch goes in to line. Neutral goes in to line and switch goes in to the line. When I push the switch the light goes on. No power to the outlet, when the the switch is on or off

What do the instructions say on how to wire it?  The switch should be for the outlet.  Edit your question if the switch is for something else.

Can you post photos of how you've wired it?
